# What is "hope hospital"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> She was awarded the Member of the Order of the British Empire 12 years ago for her contribution to the Women’s Royal Voluntary Service, a charity that provides a range of services for vulnerable people who might otherwise feel lonely.
>
> She still helps out at her local WRVS shop at **Hope Hospital**, Salford, 
>   which raises money for the charity so that it can offer services from meals on wheels for elderly people to welfare centres for soldiers in the Army.

Comment: [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salford_Royal_Hospital) explains how Salford Royal Hospital was originally known as **Hope Hospital**.

Comment: "Hope" is the former name of the [Salford Royal Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salford_Royal_Hospital) in Pendleton, Salford, England.  Because "hope" is capitalized in the article, we should assume it's a proper noun.

Comment: Hope is the name of a district of Salford.

Answer (score 2):

The capitalisation tells you that **Hope Hospital** is (or was) a specific hospital, and as the next bit of text indicates it was in Salford. More information about that hospital is rather outside the scope of this site.